405 Error or 401 Error (sometimes) on Stripe Endpoint with Next.js, Vercel, and PM2: Unable to Create Checkout Session
I'm integrating Stripe into my Next.js application deployed on Vercel. The goal is to create a checkout session through a POST request to the /api/stripe/create-checkout-session endpoint. However, I'm consistently encountering a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error or 401 Error (sometimes). This issue only occurs in production on Vercel, while everything works fine locally. I've ensured that CORS and environment variables are correctly configured. I'm using PM2 to manage the backend processes, and there are no relevant logs in Vercel to help diagnose the problem.
I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue or configure Vercel and PM2 to allow this POST request.
Backend :
app.post("/api/stripe/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Received POST request to /api/stripe/create-checkout-session");
  console.log("Request body:", req.body);

  const {
    items,
    pickupDay,
    pickupTime,
    customerName,
    customerEmail,
    customerAddress,
  } = req.body;

  // Validation des données de la requête
  if (
    !Array.isArray(items) ||
    items.length === 0 ||
    !customerName ||
    !customerEmail
  ) {
    console.error("Invalid request data:", req.body);
    return res.status(400).send("Bad Request: Invalid request data");
  }

  try {
    // Création des lignes de produit pour Stripe Checkout
    const lineItems = items.map((item) => {
      const selectedVariant = item.selectedVariant;
      let updatedTitle = item.title;

      if (selectedVariant) {
        updatedTitle = updatedTitle.replace(
          /(\d+(\.\d+)?kg)/,
          selectedVariant.weight
        );
      }

      const unitAmount = Math.round(
        parseFloat(
          selectedVariant
            ? selectedVariant.price
            : item.price.replace("€", "").replace(",", ".")
        ) * 100
      );

      return {
        price_data: {
          currency: "eur",
          product_data: {
            name: updatedTitle,
            images: [item.image],
          },
          unit_amount: unitAmount,
        },
        quantity: item.quantity,
      };
    });

    console.log("Line items:", lineItems);

    // Création de la session Stripe Checkout
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: lineItems,
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/cancel`,
      customer_email: customerEmail,
      metadata: {
        order_id: req.body.orderId || "unknown",
        pickupDay,
        pickupTime,
      },
    });

    console.log("Stripe Checkout session created:", session);

    // Réponse avec l'ID de la session
    res.json({ id: session.id });
  } catch (err) {
    // Gestion des erreurs
    console.error("Error creating checkout session:", err);
    res.status(500).send(`Internal Server Error: ${err.message}`);
  }
});

Frontend :
const createPayment = async () => {
    if (!stripeLoaded) {
      setError("Stripe.js has not loaded.");
      return;
    }

    if (!validateForm()) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      console.log("Creating payment session...");

      const response = await fetch(
        "https://ferme-en-bray.vercel.app/api/stripe/create-checkout-session",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            items: cart.map((item) => ({
              title: getUpdatedTitle(item),
              image: item.image,
              price: getUnitPrice(item),
              quantity: item.quantity,
              selectedVariant: item.selectedVariant,
            })),
            pickupDay,
            pickupTime,
            customerName,
            customerEmail,
            customerAddress,
          }),
        }
      );

      /*if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Erreur HTTP! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }*/

      const data = await response.json();

      console.log("Checkout session created:", data);

      const { id } = data;
      const stripe = window.Stripe(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
      );

      if (!stripe) {
        throw new Error("Stripe.js has not loaded.");
      }

      const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: id });

      if (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // Log detailed error information
      console.error("Error in createPayment:", err.message);
      setError("Erreur lors de la création de la commande.");
    }
  };

I attempted to configure my Express server to handle the POST request for creating a Stripe checkout session. Locally, everything worked as expected, and I was able to create a session without any issues. In production on Vercel, I expected the same result but encountered a 405 error instead.
I tried adjusting CORS settings, verifying environment variables, and checking Vercel logs, but nothing seemed to resolve the issue. I expected the POST request to succeed, but it consistently fails with the 405 error or 401 error.
